# routes.MapRoute() results in 404 Not Found

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Why would this route result in 404 Not Found when hitting url `/users/3` to call upon the route with a page number only in ASP.NET MVC:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Users", // Route name
    "users/{page}/{sortColumn}/{sortDirection}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "User", action = "Index", page = UrlParameter.Optional, sortColumn = UrlParameter.Optional, sortDirection = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
    new { page = @"\d+", sortColumn = @"[\w-]+", sortDirection = @"asc|desc" } // Route constraints
);
```

Shouldn't it be okay for me to load the route simply with the `page` parameter specified, as the `sortColumn` and `sortDirection` parameters are both set to `UrlParameter.Optional`?

**Update:**

Ok after digging up another StackOverflow answer on a similar topic, it appears if you choose to have an optional route, the constraint must also be optional.  So changing my route constraints to:
`new { page = @"\d*", sortColumn = @"[\w-]*", sortDirection = @"(asc|desc)?" }`
which simply tests for zero or more matches makes my pages load up on all accounts.

However, if I try to make a route link that reflects that (`@Html.RouteLink("test 2", "Users", new { page = 2 })`), the hyperlink is generated as `/users` not `/users/2`! Strange thing though, if I manually hit `/users/2` then the RouteLink is written as `/users/2` lol Argh! :)

Perhaps I do have to make separate routes, but this is really not desirable as I don't want to have to call upon differently named routes in `Html.RouteLink()`....
Thoughts?

Comment: If you remove the route constraints, do you still have the 404 problem?  Just wondering if there is some issue with specifying constraints on optional parameters.

Comment: yep, it's either the route constraint, or the URL is matching another route, but couldn't find an action for the route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you provide two parameters, but it expects 3 optional ones.. so it does not know which one is missing ...

In general you cannot use two consecutive optional parameters.

References

- http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/12/26/routing-issue-in-asp-net-mvc-3-rc-2.aspx
- http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/630568/url-routing-with-two-optional-parameters-unspecified-fails-on-asp-net-mvc3-rc2

Comment: That's strange, I would think I am setting up a pretty simple route. Thanks for your help; so would you suggest I break it into a few routes? I really wanted to avoid this so `Html.RouteLink()` could be consistent without calling on different named routes.

Comment: I just looked up that bug and it seems Phil Haack posted about this too. http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/20/routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters.aspx The solution might be two routes after all.